# how to set margin for flipview childs?

Tags: android, viewflipper

I am using **viewFlipper** in my application, i want to set **margins** for each **child** of **viewFlipper** . I get the **child** but unable to set margin to either left, right, bottom or top.

can anyone please help me to set margins for **viewFlipper childs**?